# Blender mirror modifier doesn't export mirrored half

Tags: blender, blender-2.61, blender-2.50, blender-2.67

When I use mirror modifier in blender and export my collide (.dae), my exported object doesn't have include the 'mirrored half' but just has the side where I didn't delete the faces.

Help?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When exporting to DAE, look in your Toolshelf Properties and try selecting "apply modifiers"[image]

**Update:**
For Blender 2.92.0 (on Mac), try here:
[image]

Comment: Upvoted. This worked for a mirrored model in Blender 2.91 exported as GLTF to use in Godot 3.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

If mirror modifier is not applied, all mirrored vertices are not considered as "true" vertices. You just have to apply the mirror modifier in object data panel.

Answer (score 0):

While exporting as glTF (.glb), checking the `Apply Modifiers` under the `Data` -> `Mesh` options fixed this issue for me. Blender version 3.6.4.

[image]